# Excel VBA Copy & Transpose Range Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy & transpose values in a Range from one Sheet to another Sheet.

```
 01 02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11

 A  B   C   D   E   F    G  H    I   J  K

 12 13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21 22

 L   M   N   O  P   Q   R   S   T    U  V
```

TO:

```
1   A   12  L
2   B   13  M
3   C   14  N
4   D   15  O
5   E   16  P
6   F   17  Q
7   G   18  R
8   H   19  S
9   I   20  T
10  J   21  U
11  K   22  V
```

So I want to go from a 4x11 Table to a 11x4 Table and I have 2212 Rows of data which gives me 553 Tables to transpose.

I already have the following code:

```
Sub Transpose_Copy_Loop()

    Dim CopyRange As Range, OutputCell As Range
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, nRows As Integer


    n = 5
    nRows = 12



    For r = 0 To n - 1

       Set CopyRange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("B1:L4").Offset(r * nRows, 0)
        CopyRange.Copy

        Set OutputCell = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Offset(r * nRows, 0)
        OutputCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The code works BUT it only takes every 4th table and transposes it to the other Sheet. So table 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16 etc. I can't seem to find the reason for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have a VBA function for that. Put your data in a 2D variant array and then you can do a: array = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(array), and then just push you data in sheet after cleaning it and you are done. I'll write a piece of code if you don't understand my comment :)

Comment: nRows is 12, so your source is moving down 12 rows each time. What's the source structure in Sheet6 - in what range is your second table?

Comment: Are the tables next to each other or separated by rows?

Comment: Hi there! THank you for your comments! 

The source structure is a large table of 2212 rows split into smaller "tables" of 4 rows and 11 colums with no separation rows

Answer (score 0):

From this:

[image]

This is the transposed value:

[image]

The code is quite flexible:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks1 As Worksheet: Set wks1 = Worksheets(1)
    Dim wks2 As Worksheet: Set wks2 = Worksheets(2)

    Dim myVar As Variant
    With Application
        myVar = .Transpose(wks1.Range("A1:D5"))
    End With

    Dim loopRows As Long
    Dim loopCols As Long

    For loopRows = LBound(myVar, 1) To UBound(myVar, 1)
        For loopCols = LBound(myVar, 2) To UBound(myVar, 2)
            wks2.Cells(loopRows, loopCols) = myVar(loopRows, loopCols)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

- The idea of the code is to write the values from the range to a multidimensional array -
  `myVar = Application.Transpose(wks1.Range("A1:D5"))`
- Once this is done, then looping through the array and writing the values to the corresponding row and column gets what is needed.

Comment: This works well but only for one "table". It doesn't seem to loop for the rest of the array. What may cause this?

Comment: @Thomas - What array? For `A1:D5` it works quite well.  It would work also for `B3:D100`.

Comment: Ok Vityata, thank you for the explanation and it does work for the whole array now, but the only issue I am still seeing is that the transposed data is being added along the rows sideways in the second sheet, but not down in the same 4 columns.

Comment: @Thomas - I am missing your point. However, if it is that `B3:D100` would add data starting from `A1`, then this is somehow easily adjustable with an `Offset()` function.

Comment: No it copies and transposes the array correctly, but it transposes it sideways and not downwards. Basically right now it transposes an array A1:CFP13 but I need the array to be transposed into "A1:D5600" 

I was thinking of adding something like:

`Set CopyRange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("B1:L4").Offset(r * nRows, 0)
        CopyRange.Copy

        Set OutputCell = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Offset(r * nRows, 0)
        OutputCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True`